# Tracking white color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to understand how to work with ROI, but the following code is not working as expected.

I have a white ball walking through a black background, and I want to detect and keep tracking of this ball. Unfortunately, the square does not move.
I think the problem is the color array, but after trying many values, I still haven't found the correct solution.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('oieee.avi')
ret,frame = cap.read()

r,h,c,w = 485,50,890,50  
track_window = (c,r,w,h)
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 0., 240.)), np.array((255.,15.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)
        ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)
        x,y,w,h = track_window
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        cv2.imshow('img2',frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)
    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

A print screen of my video https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRqy0.jpg

Comment: If you have a binary image, with compression artefacts, it might be that your HSV values are going crazy. Maybe try to include something like `ret,frame = (cap.read() > 155).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: btw. if your final application is also a white ball with that black background, I would not worry about using anything more fancy than using `skimage.measure.label` and `regionsprops` to detect the ball and extract its location

Comment: Can you include your `oieee.avi?` file. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#Help others reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks @P.R. and @ boardrider. P.R. I read about your ideas, and them look great, regionsprops would be fine, but I am Windows user, and I don't have a clue how to install this. Do you think that findcontours will work? I tried before, but I had some problems related to arrays. boardrider https://vid.me/HEF3.

Comment: you can install skimage like any other regular python package with `pip install skimage`. If you have anaconda installed (I highly recommend this), then skimage is already installed. Try it out: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_regionprops.html